Decompositions of generic Fourier coefficients of degenerate Eisenstein series for maximal parabolics
Let $G$ be a quasi-split semi-simple group over $\mathbb Q$. Let $P=MU$ be a parabolic of $G$ over $\mathbb Q$ with unipotent radical $U$ and Levi $M$. Let $\chi: M \to \mathbb G_m$ be a character of $M$.
I am interested in the Eisenstein series $Eis(g, \phi), g \in G(\mathbb A)$ from the parabolic induction $\phi \in Ind_{P}^G(\chi)$. For simplicity, assume that $\chi$ is unramified and $\phi$ is spherical with $\phi(1)=1$.
Let $\psi: U \to \mathbb C$ be a generic character. In the case of $P=B$ is a Borel, the $\psi$-th Whittaker coefficient of $Eis(g,\phi)$ can be decomposed into local Whittaker functions (due to multiplicity one of Whittaker models). Moreover, it can be computed as a Jacquet integral (where $w_0$ is the longest element in the Weyl group of $W$)
$$
\int_{U(\mathbb A)} \phi(w_0ng)\psi(n)^{-1} dn.
$$
In particular, it can be decomposed as explicitly local Whittaker functions and computed by the Casselman-Shalika formula. See Jacquet H. Fonctions de Whittaker associées aux groupes de Chevalley[J]. Bulletin de la société mathématique de France, 1967, 95: 243-309. The proof is based on Bruhat decomposition of $G$.
Here is my question: assume that $P$ is a maximal parabolic. Do we still have a decomposition of $\psi$-th Whittaker coefficient of $Eis(g,\phi)$ into explicit local Whittaker functions (by similar Jacquet integrals)？
For non-generic Fourier coefficients, some examples have been studied in https://arxiv.org/abs/2004.14244v3. Thank you for any further references.
